# Updating Twitter profile picture with iOS SLRequest results in error 215 bad authentication data

Tags: ios, twitter, acaccount, slrequest

I am trying to post new profile picture according to Twitter's documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile_image and here is my code:

```
NSData *jpeg = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.9);
NSString *base64 = [jpeg base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_image.json"];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"image" : base64
                         };
SLRequest *request =
[SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                   requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                             URL:url
                      parameters:params];
[request setAccount:self.twitterAccount];
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                     NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse,
                                     NSError *error) {
    ...
}
```

But URL response is:

```
errors =     (
            {
        code = 215;
        message = "Bad Authentication data.";
    }
);
```

What am I doing wrong? My `ACAccount` is valid (I've just tried signing out from and into Twitter in Settings.app).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807221/get-twitter-friends-list/54838712#54838712

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems fine, but you must be missing something.

Make sure that:

- That your Twitter account is connected and is listed in the Settings app Twitter settings. I know you already checked, but it is essential that you verify it. Maybe even restart your phone and make sure your Twitter handle is there afterwards.
- That your app has requested and granted permission to
  access the account (using the `requestAccessToAccountsWithType` method). Once permission is granted, you should see your app listed in the Twitter settings (in the Settings app) under "ALLOW THESE APPS TO USE YOUR ACCOUNT".
- The Twitter account that you're setting to the `SLRequest` is valid and is not `nil`.

Given the conditions above I was abled to modify my profile image successfully just now. Here's a sample code based on the code you've provided:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
{
    if (granted)
    {
        NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
        ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts lastObject];

        NSData *jpeg = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.jpg"], 0.9);
        NSString *base64 = [jpeg base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
        SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                          URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_image.json"]
                                                   parameters:@{@"image" : base64}];
        [request setAccount:twitterAccount];
        [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                             NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse,
                                             NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"%@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil]);
         }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: It was my bad. I don't know how I made such a simple mistake but my `self.twitterAccount` was nil. In some of my tests, it wasn't, I have no idea why it didn't work at that time. But then it was always nil. After getting a valid Twitter account object there, it worked.

Comment: Could you please add a little update to your answer regarding checking if twitterAccount is nil, which was the actual solution to my issue, so I can reward you the bounty?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu done (added to the list of "things to make sure"). Thanks! :)